# Recover data from RAID0

Tags: raid

Is it possible to recover data from a RAID0 hard drive when the other hard drive has failed?

Comment: The short answer is "no" and the long answer is "how much money have you got?"

Comment: For future reference, the zero in RAID-0 is the amount of data you can most likely recover if a drive fails.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only data that's on that disk - which is unlikely to be of any use (you may conceivably be able to snag some small files that lived only on the still-functioning disk).

RAID-0 has no consideration for recovery from a drive failure - its purpose is pure performance.

Time to dust off the backups!

Comment: Ok makes sense, thanks for your answer. Luckily we have a backup!

Answer (score 6):

Possible? Yes.

Likely? No.

Answer (score 4):

As posted above, you're screwed.

If you don't want to pay AU$1000 (minimum) to a data recovery specialist, you can try removing the drive from the RAID array (probably from the controller) and boot the PC. Run a program like Recover My Files and scan the drive (it has progressively aggressive scan settings built in).

If the file allocation table has been lost, the likelihood of recovering many files uncorrupted is minute, but it's a possibility and could be cost effective.

Comment: "you're screwed" +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

How much is this data worth to you?  If it's critical, shut both drives off and call a data recovery company now.  It's probably going to be costly, but they may be able to restore the data.  If you start screwing around with the drives, you could prevent them from being able to help.

If it's not critical, try putting the failed drive in a plastic bag, then into a freezer for awhile.  This might let the drive work long enough for you to copy data off the array.